# HTML Email Signature Fall Back Font

Tags: html, css, email, fonts

I am trying to create an HTML/CSS email signature, but am having issues with font compatibility across devices. My code snippet for the bolded name section will revert to a serif font when the first fonts are not available on the device (Gotham Black and/or Montserrat). I am specifically testing on outgoing (sending) email client being Outlook, and incoming (viewing) email client being Gmail. What am I missing in this to have the fallback fonts not being hit? (Looks like just reverting to Times New Roman which is default web font.) Can I ONLY use web safe fonts?

**Snippet:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="margin: 10px 0; font-size: 12px;">
            <span style="font-family: Gotham Black, Montserrat, Tahoma, sans-serif; color: black; font-weight: 900;">JOHN DOE</span> <br/>
            <span style="font-family: Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #A6A6A6;">
                <b>123.456.7890</b> mobile <br/>
                <span style="color: #A6A6A6;">123 MAIN STREET | UNIT 123 | SAN FRANCISCO, CA | 12345</span> <br/>
                <span><a style="color:#A6A6A6;" href="https://www.website.com" target="_blank">www.website.com</a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi did you find a solution? I’m having the exact same issue. If you’re not using a web safe font first, it incorrectly substitutes bold text with a serif font instead of using the fallback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just use one of the websafe fonts that looked close. Seemed too finicky between systems and such to use anything other than those few web-safe fonts. I can't remember exactly what list of web-safe fonts I tested thru as there seems to be a small dispute over what fonts are really "web-safe" lol. I landed on Calibri, then tested the font on a few computers and browsers just to be sure, and passed around the company. Please let me know if anyone finds a different solution to this, would love to know!